# meaning of "a limitation of biotechnological options as a way of broadening them"

Tags: meaning

meaning of "a limitation of biotechnological options as a way of broadening them"

"When the Universal Declaration of Human Rights guarantees “life, liberty, 
and security of person” in Article 3,and many national constitutions 
grant special protection to the life and health of their citizens, **these 
guarantees are not so much a limitation of biotechnological options 
as a way of broadening them**"

Comment: The meaning is that there is no real meaning; it's just spin. The author will probably expand on it in the next paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial title is misleading. It should read:

> meaning of “not so much a limitation of biotechnological options as a
>   way of broadening them”

The structure is

> It's not so much an A as a B.

*It's not so much a restriction on free speech as a way of controlling seditious communications.*

Answer (score 1):

It is stated that the Universal Declaration of Human Rights includes guarantees of “life, liberty, and security of person”.

Clearly, there are numerous ways of achieving this, and examples some of the known ones are (presumably) explicitly listed in the declaration.

The phrase "not so much a limitation of biotechnological options as a way of broadening them" is intended to indicate that the list of examples cited in the declaration is not intended to be exhaustive.  On the contrary, it states, the intention is that any future innovations (perhaps biotechnical in nature) that strengthen the guarantees of “life, liberty, and security of person” are to be considered supported under the declaration.